# Merge 'saveas' and 'save-as' tags on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

The title pretty much explains it. The are two tags on SO, namely [save-as](/questions/tagged/save-as) and [saveas](/questions/tagged/saveas) that are both used for the same purpose. Should we merge them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, and [saveas](/questions/tagged/saveas) should be made a synonym of [save-as](/questions/tagged/save-as).

Comment: I already tried to create the synonym but didn't have the 5 tag points to do it.

Comment: Making one tag a synonym of the other tag is just the beginning. Merging the tags should be the first step, and moderators can do both at the same time.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, yep, actually though I think when a tag-synonym is created, it automatically changes tags out.  (Though I just saw a [bug on BCG](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/466/please-synonym-opening-and-openings) where that didn't work right).

Comment: @Lance Roberts As far as I remember, making a tag a synonym of the other, when the first tag was already used in questions, doesn't alter the questions where the tag was already used; after it is made a synonym, the tag will not appear in the new questions. That is also the reason why moderators, when merging two tags can opt to make one the synonym of the other; for what I remember, they can also merge two tags when making a tag a synonym of another one. It could be they changed something since I am not a moderator anymore (which happened 22 days ago).

Comment: @kiamlaluno, since I haven't been a mod, you're probably right, I just didn't realize it was manual, since it's a logical choice for automation (though you will end up with some dupe tags, but you could do an immediate search to pick those out).  that probably explains what happened on BCG.

Comment: We can't propose a synonym for this because of the question counts. Retagging spree anyone? It's only 32 questions.

Comment: @Jon, I know I can't, but can't mods or waffles himself make it happen.  I'll put it on my list of things to do.

Comment: @Jon, I did some of them, and someone else pitched in, so now you can create the synonym.

Comment: I don't have the ability to add the synonym, sorry.