# Delete [saveas]

Tags: feature-request, tags, burninate-request

I've been going through the [Clean up of hyphenated tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135985/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags/135993#135993) list, and retagged all [saveas](/questions/tagged/saveas) questions as [save-as](/questions/tagged/save-as) (props to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96071/merge-saveas-and-save-as-tags-on-stackoverflow) for further guidance).

Would it be possible for a moderator to blacklist / delete / burninate (as appropriate) the [saveas](/questions/tagged/saveas) tag, as it's currently sitting at 0 questions?
Or does this happen automatically?

Comment: At 0 questions, the tag will automatically get removed. Blacklisting isn't really done often as this needs to be done by the developers. I think there's functionality to prevent the tag from getting recreated since [tag:save-as] already exists.

Comment: @Dukeling Great stuff, thanks for the clarification :)